# How to perform side effect only once for Rxjs Observables?

Tags: rxjs

I've got the following scenario, with a BehaviorSubject used to emit a boolean.
I'm exposing the subject as an observable so it can be subscribed to, and i would expect it to be a hot observable but i guess i got something wrong.

```
private source$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
obs$ = this.source$.pipe(share(), tap(_=> console.log('Some side effect'));
```

Now, when i subscribe to it in `n` places and emit the next value i get `n` console logs, but using the share operator i'd expect only one.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: everything **after** the share will be shared. So just put the tap before

Comment: You have switch the order of operators. You have `n` subscriptions to `tap()` and `n` subscriptions to `share()`. `.pipe(tap(), share())`

Comment: Also, if the source emits and you subscribe later on and still expect to get the latest value, instead of share you can use `shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I didnt' realize the importance of order.

Comment: Can one of you guys post their comment as a answer in order for this question to be moved away from the unanswered section :)